# Matching Card Game in Java

Tags: java

**Hi,**

**I'm making a matching card game and I don't understand how to actually do it. I was hoping someone could help explain what I can do to figure this out.**

**The following are the specifications:**

In a card game of Pairs the goal is to turn over pairs of matching cards.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_(game)
Here are the rules for the variation of Pairs we consider.

At the start of the game, there are n cards face-down, where n is a multiple of 4. There are 4 cards
of each type, and the cards are labeled with letters a, b, . . . . For example, if n==24, there are 6
types of cards: a, b, c, d, e, and f. Say 1*4<=n and n<=4*26.

At each turn, the player flips 2 cards, one at a time, that are face-down. If the 2 flips are of the
same type, the matched cards are left face-up. If the 2 flips mismatch, the mismatched cards are
returned to the face-down position. The game ends when all cards are matched, and the score is
the total number of flips made. (Flipping a pair of cards counts as 2 flips, so the best possible score
is n flips.)

Write a pubic class titled MatchCardGame with the following members that implement this game
of Pairs. The starter code in PlayCard.java should give you an idea of how MatchCardGame is
used.

MatchCardGame should have no other public fields, methods, and constructors aside from the ones
specified. However, it may and should have additional private fields, methods, or constructors.

The field

public final int n;

is the size of the game set by the constructor.

The constructor

public MatchCardGame(int n);

initializes a card game with a total of n cards. Assume n is a multiple of 4 and that 4<=n && n<=4*26.
Without shuffling (explained in Problem 2) cards 0,1,2, and 3 should be a, cards 4,5,6, and 7 should
be b, and so on.

The method

public String boardToString();

converts the state of the board to an appropriate String representation. You have freedom to
choose your own representation, but it must reasonably represent the state of the game.

The method

public boolean flip(int i);

plays card number i. If card i cannot be played because it’s face-up, or if i is an invalid card
number, then return false. If i is a card number that can be played, play card i and return
true.

The method

public boolean wasMatch();

returns true if the previous pair was a match and returns false otherwise. This method should be
called only after flip has been successfully called an even number of times and before flipMismatch
is called. (A successful call of flip is a call that results in a flip and returns true.)

The method

public char previousFlipIdentity();

returns the face of the previously flipped card as a char. This method should only be called after
a card has been flipped.

The method

public void flipMismatch();

reverts the mismatched pair to face-down position. This method should only be called after a 2
calls of flip results in a mismatch.

The method

public boolean gameOver();

returns true if all cards have been matched and the game is over and returns false otherwise.
The method
public int getFlips();

returns the total number of card flips that have been performed so far.

Remark. MatchCardGame represents the physical state of the game, not the player. MatchCardGame
has nothing to do with game strategies a human or AI player might employ.

Remark. The problem specifies how these methods should be used. For example, the input n of
MatchCardGame’s constructor needs to be a multiple of 4. You do not have to do any sort of error
handling when these requirements are violated, although using asserts will help debugging.

**So far, I have the following:**

```
public class MatchCardGame {
//Private classes
private boolean facingup;
private char[] board;
private int flips = 0;
private int matches = 0;
private int currentflip;

//Public classes
public final int n;

public MatchCardGame(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i % 4 == 0) {
            this.board[i] = 'a';
        }
        else if (i % 4 == 1) {
            this.board[i] = 'b';
        }
        else if (i % 4 == 2) {
            this.board[i] = 'c';
        }
        else {
            this.board[i] = 'd';
        }
    }
}

public String boardToString() {
    String stringboard = "";
    for (int i; i < n; i++) {
        if (facingup){
            stringboard += stringboard + "[" + this.board[i] + "] ";
        }
        else {
            stringboard += "[-] ";
        }
    }
    return stringboard;
}

public boolean flip(int i) {
    flips++;
    if (i < 0 || i >= n || currentflip == ((int) this.board[i]) % 32) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        if (flips % 2 != 0) {
            currentflip = ((int) board[i]) % 32;
            facingup = true;
            return true;
        }
        else if (board[i] == this.board[i]) {
            currentflip = -1;
            this.facingup = true;
            board [i] = '0';
            this.board[i] = '0';
            matches += 2;
            return true;
        }
    }
}

public boolean wasMatch() {
    if (currentflip == -1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public char previousFlipIdentity() {
    return board [i];
}

public void flipMismatch() {
    facingup = false;
    this.facingup = false;

}

public boolean gameOver() {
    if (matches == n) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public int getFlips() {
    return flips;
}}
```

**Any assistance would be appreciated.**

Comment: `private boolean facingup` - you need to know per-card if the card is facing up, not one flag for the whole game.

Comment: You'll need state to store which cards were flipped for two flip calls, and whether the result of two flips was a match or not, to return from wasMatch().

Comment: But the instructions seem reasonably clear to me. Pick a method and have a go implementing it? Then add extra state and extra logic as you need to to make that work. (Or plan it all in advance - whatever's easiest for you.) I'm not sure whether to recommend you start with flip() or not - it's definitely going to be the most complicated, but maybe you can start it simply and build it up. What you've got for it at the moment, the bounds check, is an OK start but there's lots more to do.

Comment: I've made somewhat reasonable changes...

Comment: One of my bigger worries is how I can count the flips? Should I create a counter in one of the methods? Will it be accessible in other methods, particularly the getFlips() one?

Comment: No, the flip count should be straightforward: make a new private int to store the count; every time you successfully flip a card in flip() increment that count, and then you can return that int from getFlips(). Yes, a private int field will be accessible to all methods in the class.

Comment: OK, a quick comment on what you've got so far. boardToString won't compile, because it's supposed to return a string and it's not. The return shouldn't be in the for loop; build up a string using the for loop and then return the string. You should also check if each card is flipped or not: if it is, add the letter to the string, else add something else e.g. '#' or '.'. You don't yet have state to know if individual cards are flipped.

Comment: flip() will need to check if the card number it's been given is already flipped and return false if it is; then it will need to change the flipped state for the given card and store somewhere the number of the card, and you will need to store two flipped card numbers at once. Either make two private ints and e.g. set them to -1 to mean nothing flipped, and then set them back to -1 later, or make an array or list and add the cards to those as you flip them. Then increase the flipped count.

Comment: wasMatch won't compile because there's no i. You'll need to check the two stored flipped card numbers from flipped and see if the letters match.

Comment: Alright... I incorporated some of those changes...

Comment: `return true; flipcount++;` The increment needs to go before the `return`. In any case Java will raise an error for 'unreachable statement' so this won't compile. (Are you testing that the code compiles as you go? Your IDE should also highlight this as an error.)

Comment: The testing isn't working because of all the errors; I currently don't use an IDE but rather the CMD. So, I use an online compiled but it doesn't efficiently list the errors, making it difficult to spot them...

Comment: Also, could you explain your suggestions for flip() further? @Rup

Comment: Is this an assignment for school?

Comment: Yes... in case it matters, the prof allowed us to consult other sources for help as long as we don't directly plagiarize code...

Comment: It is important for some of the people here. The types of answers you get might have been different had they known. As you have deliberately kept this from us, I will not help.

Comment: I understand; first time user here so it's good to know :)

Answer (score 5):

Try to walk through it in your mind.

- You have been given a set of cards
- One card, `x` is flipped
- Other card is flipped next; if it's the same as the previous `x`, remove both cards
- If it's not the same as the previous, ignore both flips.
- Continue these steps till all cards are matched and no cards are remaining

So to convert it into code, what are the things you need to keep track of?

- All cards and their types (`a`, `b` and so on)
- State of card: Flipped or not flipped
- General state of all cards: Matched or still present (remember, if it's matched, we remove it)
- Number of flips

How can we keep track of this?

- We can keep track of the type of card in the array `char[] board`
- Maintain a `private int flips` to keep track of number of flips, and `private int matches` to keep track of matches, initially `0`
- Maintain a `private int currentlyFlippedCard` to store the 1st flipped card's index.
- If it's the first flip, store it in `currentlyFlippedCard`.
- Increment `int flips` every time a card is flipped(`flips++`).
- If it's the second flip, check if the type of card matches the type of card in `currentlyFlippedCard`.

  - How do you know if the flip is first or second? Because we increment `flips` every time.
  - For the first flip, `flip == 1`; second, `flip == 2`; if it's flipped again, it becomes `flip == 3`, which we should take as the first flip.
  - From this, we can say that when `flip` is odd, it's the first flip, and when `flip` is even, it's the second.
- If both flips do not match: don't make any changes.
- If both flips match: change both index of both flips to `'0'` in `char[] board` to mark it as inactive; increment `int matches` by `2`
- So next time flip(`i`) is called, check if `board[i] != '0'`, which will make sure it's still active in the game
- How do you know if the game is over? If all cards are matched, game is over. So if `matches == n`, all cards are matched.
- You need to know if the previous flip was a match(for `wasMatch()`). For this, you can maintain a `boolean` to keep track of it; or another way is, you can use the variable `currentlyFlippedCard` itself. 
  For the second way:

  - When second flip is not a match, do nothing(`currentlyFlippedCard` will have the index of previous flip, meaning `currentlyFlippedCard >= 0`)
  - When second flip is a match, along with incrementing `matches`, set `currentlyFlippedCard = -1`.
  - When you need to call `wasMatch()`, return `true` if `flips` is even and `currentlyFlippedCard == -1`.
- For `boardToString()`, just put all chars from `board[]` in a `String` one by one using a loop.

  - Here, `0` will mean it's matched; you can just add an `if` check to see if it's == `0` and change it to another character while inserting into the `String`.
  - Same goes for currently flipped card; you can just check when that index comes, and add a `*` or something to indicate it's flipped.

This is a brief overview, you just have to convert it into code. I have so far refrained from adding actual code, since it'll help you if you try it out yourself.

All the best, keep learning! :)

Edit 1(after comments):

I'm guessing `wasMatch()` is called after every 2nd flip? I assumed it won't be, and accidentally put the incrementing indexes in `flip()`.

So since `wasMatch()` is a separate method, you can maintain 2 variables for the flipped cards(say `currentlyFlippedCard1` and `currentlyFlippedCard2`), and increment during `wasMatch()`.

As for `flipMismatch()`: Specs say it should 'revert it to facedown position'. You can either make no changes, or change `currentlyFlippedCard1` and `currentlyFlippedCard2` to some default value like `-2`.

Edit 2(after comments):

For `previousFlipIdentity()`:

- Check `int flips` to see if the previous flip was first or second flip(by checking if `int flips` is odd or even)
- If first flip, return `board[currentlyFlippedCard1]`
- If second flip, return `board[currentlyFlippedCard2]`

**My suggestion is:** implement core methods you know first. Once you get some methods running, you will have a better idea, and you can add in more functionality.

Comment: Your comments make it seems way easier to understand :) I'm curious though, am I incrementing matches by 2 in the "wasmatch()" or in "flip(int i)" method? Same goes for changing the indexes; in which method should I do this? In particular, I've edited my code above (in the post)^; is that what you meant?

Comment: Also, could you suggest what I can do for the flipMismatch() method? I can't seem call board [i] in methods aside from flip(int i) and MatchCardGame(int n)...

Comment: @TRONIIX, edited my answer to include clarifications.

Comment: Done! One last thing, for the previousFlipIdentity(), how do I return the face of the card? I can't call board[i] in this method...

Comment: @TRONIIX, you can use the same `board[]` array, just not with `i`; check the edit 2

Comment: Yep! Thanks! @Bojan Krkic